# JS Object Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have a fairly complex object, and have included a simplified version(taken out unnecessary functions). It is not working when I initiate it and I do not know why. Safari told me:`[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.data.steps[index]')`
But I don't know why. Here's the code:

```js
function Stepper (url) {
    this.index = 0;
    this.url = url;
    this.stepsn = 0;
    this.data = {}
    this.init = function () {
        var XHR = $.getJSON(this.url, function (json) {
            this.data = json;
            this.stepsn = this.data.steps.length;
        });
    };
    this.getstep = function (index) {
        return this.data.steps[index];
    };

    this.init();
}
\\Instantiation
var url = "lesson.json"; //lession.json is valid(I checked)
var stepper = new Stepper(url);
```

Thanks for helping, if you do.

```
Safari 8.0.7  Included jquery 1.11.3
```

Comment: Do a console.log(json). I think json.steps is undefined.

Comment: `this.data` looks like an empty object; where is `this.data.steps` supposed to come from?

Comment: `this` inside `$.getJSON` is not your object.

Comment: @Karl-Andre Thanks Karl! That was exactly what I missed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forward slashes that you are using in your comment are a syntax error. Also you have don't have a `steps` key in your `this.data` object which is why that line is throwing an error.

I also used bind in your `.getJSON` call so you refer to the Stepper object. See fixed code below:

```js
function Stepper (url) {
    this.index = 0;
    this.url = url;
    this.stepsn = 0;
    this.data = {}
    this.init = function () {
        var XHR = $.getJSON(this.url, function (json) {
            this.data = json;
            this.stepsn = this.data.steps.length;
        }).bind(this);
    };
    this.getstep = function (index) {
        return this.data.steps[index];
    };

    this.init();
}
//Instantiation
var url = "lesson.json"; //lession.json is valid(I checked)
var stepper = new Stepper(url);
```